# Show markers on gmap from all nodes exposed in view

Tags: views, location, google-maps

I'm using gmap module to mark job locations on a map. It now shows all locations of content type: jobs. Is there any way I can only mark the displayed jobs from my view block? I filter the jobs through exposed filters.

EDIT:

Just going to add this code here, might be useful for some. It puts the attachment in a block so you have more control over it.

```
<?php
//Puts gmap attachment in block so it's easier to theme

function gmap_block_block_info() {
  $blocks['gmap_attachment'] = array(
    'info' => t('Gmap Attachment'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function gmap_block_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  if ($delta == 'gmap_attachment') {
   // $block['subject'] = t('Gmap Attachment');
    // Load the view.
    $view = views_embed_view('jobs_view_block', 'gmap_attachment');
                        //('machine_name_view', 'machine_name_display)
    if ($view) {
      $block['content'] = $view;
    }
    else {
      $block['content'] = t('The view is empty');
    }
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up the map display as an attachment, you can set it to inherit the exposed filters that you've defined for your job listing. You'll get one set of exposed filters that controls both the listing and the map.

There may be some issues - see this [blog post](http://www.jodevmo.com/blog/drupal-7-gmap-and-views/) by someone solving what looks like the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, just adding it as an attachment did the trick, really simple!